# What does it mean to have a flat classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

I would like to know what a flat classpath is and what it means.

Also, I would like to know if there are there other kinds of classpaths.

Comment: It probably refers to not having any of the following: multiple directories on the classpath, a classloader hierarchy (such as in a web app), or jar files embedded in other jar files. Do you have a link to where you read the term?

Comment: @Thilo It is from a book called Component Oriented Design and Assembly. I was reading about OSGi when they mentioned it, but they didn't explain what it meant.

Comment: The link explains the plat classpath and other approaches:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/findingclasses.html

Comment: OSGi has a particularily complex classloading arrangement. The goal is to isolate the dependencies of each bundle. You can even have conflicting versions of the same jar file in OSGi. In general, Java allows you to build all kinds of custom classloader hierarchies. Compared to a "flat classpath" this incurs some overhead, but allows for better modularization.